# How to add an event listener to a Kendo UI view?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

`$('#my-view').on('show', showHandler)`

Doesn't work.  Using data-show is not an option either because the code that sets/unsets the event is within class that is instantiated later.   Also creating the view programatically and passing in the event handler doesn't work because I need to set the event on/off at different times.

Is this not possible with kendoUI?  If not, why?  This seems like such an incredibly obvious feature to relay those events to the element themselves similar to what is possible with jquery ui widgets.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var view = $('#my-view');
var widget = kendo.widgetInstance(view);
widget.bind('show', showHandler);
```

Comment: However views widgets are not created until they are shown!   So if you call widgetInstance before the view is first shown, you will get undefined instead of the widget which is problematic also.

Answer (score 0):

Better answer, just delegate the events yourself so the code in the question actually works:

```
<div data-role="view" ... data-show="onShow">...</div>
```

and

```
function onShow () {
    this.element.trigger('show');
}
```

Now the it works :).   The problem I still has was that 'show' isn't triggered when a view is first shown if it is the first view shown.   Er, so yeah I had to add some extra code for that too like this:

```
if ($('#my-view').is(':visible')) {
    $('#my-view').trigger('show');
}
```

Lame but it works.